# Reset coordinate system inside foreignObject

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the following HTML:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="red"></rect>
   <g transform="scale(0.5)">
     <foreignObject width="100" height="100">
       <div>
         
       </div>
     </foreignObject>
  </g>
</svg>
```

With this CSS:

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 10px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/puchm/pen/ExOdyym) (change the scale manually to see my problem)

The problem is that when I change the scale of the transform, the border stroke width changes as well. I honestly wouldn't expect it to do so since it's a foreign object which shouldn't be affected by the coordinate system of the `svg` but it is.

Why is the `div` affected by the transform? I would like the border of the `div` to always have the same stroke width regardless of the scale of the coordinate system.

I know about the `vector-effect` `non-scaling-stroke` which I could use on a `rect` element or other SVG elements but I need to use HTML elements for other reasons.

Comment: This is because that's what transforms do - they don't tend to keep in mind borders etc, they just transform what is basically a box into another box. Your div is rendered at 100x100, then scaled at .5, changing the `stroke` visually. Just like with `CSS` transform, they don't care. SVG supports `vector-effect` for native objects, which could b useful, but otherwise, you're not solving it like this.